# How do I make Puppet serve the proper certificate?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to connect my puppetmaster and my puppet client. I've been having trouble with the certificates. I was originally trying to use the puppetmaster's IP address (because we don't have DNS set up), but now I think I'll have to edit the hosts file when I set up a new machine to map `puppet` to its ip.

So once I do that, I'm still having issues. Some background: on the master, I had tried to get rid of the server certificate a few times and recreate a new one. I think that's causing the problem because the log is saying it was revoked. `devtest` is the puppet agent.

This is what happens when I try to test the agent.

```
[root@devtest puppet]# puppet agent --test --server puppet
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Wrapped exception:
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Wrapped exception:
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Could not retrieve fact='ipaddress', resolution='<anonymous>': Could not execute 'host devtest': command not found
Could not retrieve fact='ipaddress', resolution='<anonymous>': Could not execute 'host devtest': command not found
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=servername.mydomain.com]
```

If I'm understanding the first error properly, it's saying the certificate presented by the `master` server for `servername.mydomain.com` has been revoked. (I've edited the log to remove the actual server name and domain).

So I want to have `puppetmaster` serve up a new certificate. I go onto it, and stop the Apache service (so it doesn't hold the certificate in memory).

I then delete the ssl folder, and try to regenerate the puppet certificate:

```
[ZachDev@mon puppet]$ sudo puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
Info: Creating a new SSL key for ca
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for ca
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): 17:F7:19:23:E6:99:BD:DD:3D:E6:F1:DD:35:8A:A6:81:8D:96:7D:15:63:EC:51:21:65:96:D1:24:FA:97:1B:07
Notice: Signed certificate request for ca
Info: Creating a new certificate revocation list
Info: Creating a new SSL key for 10.128.119.155
Info: csr_attributes file loading from /etc/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for 10.128.119.155
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): BE:C8:B9:FF:1F:7A:49:1F:4F:97:E4:37:A3:9E:12:19:6F:41:3B:DB:DE:CB:AA:03:D8:02:94:D1:68:49:13:9C
Notice: 10.128.119.155 has a waiting certificate request
Notice: Signed certificate request for 10.128.119.155
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest 10.128.119.155 at '/etc/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/10.128.119.155.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest 10.128.119.155 at '/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests/10.128.119.155.pem'
Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.6.2
^CNotice: Caught INT; calling stop
```

That worked. Now I restart Apache, and get an error. `systemctl status httpd.service` doesn't say anything useful, but /var/log/httpd/puppet-server-example.com_ssl_error.log does:

```
[Fri Aug 01 18:48:49.383002 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 25661] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Aug 01 18:48:49.383028 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 25661] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for servername.mydomain.com:8140 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 01 18:48:49.383044 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25661] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Fri Aug 01 18:48:49.383071 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25661] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

At this point, I'm just guessing at what the config file settings should be. I assume some config files need to be changed -- either the Apache config or the Puppet config, but at this point I'm not sure what the right certificates are. I have certificates in `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` and in `/etc/puppet/ssl`.

Comment: So is `server.mydomain.com` the FQDN of the master or the agent?

Comment: It's the master -- but unfortunately, like I said, we don't have DNS set up, so I'm not sure what exactly I need to do to make it work. I've added `server.mydomain.com` to the hosts file on the client. I'll have to make sure I'm connecting to the master via that, and not the IP address. Anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your setup. You are indeed right that you need to

1. pick an FQDN for the master and make sure the agents can resolve it

   - via respective `hosts` file or
   - through `dnsmasq`
2. tell the master to use that name as its SSL CN

First, make sure the master uses the correct name. Add this to `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` on the master:

```
[master]
certname=server.mydomain.com
```

Restart the master. It should sign a new certificate for itself (note how it considered `10.128.119.155` to be its name and used that as the CN - this is not sensible).

Next, make sure Apache uses this certificate instead of the CA certificate.

```
SSLCertificateFile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/server.mydomain.com.pem
```

(You can make sure `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` is the correct path using `puppet master --configprint ssldir`).

Your master should now have a valid certificate to present. If an agent reaches it through its FQDN, the SSL handshake should succeed.